# Making posts from WordPress in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, wordpress, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

So I'm working as a software apprentice and I have to re-build a website.
Basically what the website does is: post different things (events,news,etc.) and all these posts have like a preview and then when you click on it, it takes you to the post.
The way thay it works is: in the code it has a template for the design of every post. But if you want to make a new post, you need to do it from WordPress.
So know I'm looking the way to do that, I think that the first developer used json to "call" the data from the database in WordPress (I guess).

So I hope that someone can help me with a different or a easier option to do that.

Thanks

Comment: It's slightly unclear what you're asking. You want to use Ruby to get data from WordPress? What have you tried so far?

Comment: What they asked me to do is that the author of the post can write the info of the post in WordPress and then the people will be able to see the post in the website. Is like reading posts from WordPress in a rails app.

Answer (score 3):

There are various gems that integrate with the wordpress api. And you could always write your own api wrapper.

https://github.com/jordandobson/wordpress

https://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_APIs

https://github.com/zachfeldman/rubypress